# Karma jasmine do not mock service method after changing to promise

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a component that calls a service method.
When the service method returned an observable, it worked great,
but when I changed it to promise, the test started to fail.

The change in the test was:

**Working:**

Test:

```
const getPackListSpy = ppackService.listPacks.and.returnValue( of(packListResult) );

it('should show pack list', fakeAsync(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      tick(5000);
      fixture.detectChanges();
      const packsInView = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.packName').length;

      expect(packsInView).toBe(2);
    }));
```

Component:

```
this.protocolPackService.listPacks()
      .subscribe((packs) => {
        this.packs = packs;
      });
```

**Not working after changing to promise:**

Test:

```
const getPackListSpy = ppackService.listPacks.and.returnValue( Promise.resolve(packListResult) );
```

Component:

```
this.packs = await this.protocolPackService.listPacks();
```

The issue is that my list of items in the template does not show any data (which is based on `this.packs`) after changing to Promise. The component works fine in both cases outside the test environment.

Any idea what could have gone wrong?

Component code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getUploadedPacks();
 }

  async getUploadedPacks() {
    const packs = await this.protocolPackService.listPacks();
    this.packs = [{
      name: 'pack'
     }];
    this.packs = this.packs.concat(packs);
   }
```

Service:

```
listPacks(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get('packs').toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: Any chance you are using `async` pipe on `packs` in your template ?

Comment: @ashish.gd nope, i don't use `async` pipe. my component works, the test not.

Comment: Also, have you marked the method containing the `await` statement with `async` keyword ?

Comment: Indeed, I would get a compilation error otherwise.

Comment: @TheUnreal could you please provide some more details about your component and tests?
It would be perfect to clone this stackblitz example and add your example there.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing

Comment: @shohrukh I added the component code. It's really strange that the test does not show any pack since I initalize the array with one default item, regardless of the service

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some methods for testing async code, for example `fakeAsync/tick` [from angular](https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-fakeasync) testing library:

```
it('should show items', fakeAsync(() => {
  const { comp, el, fixture } = setup();

  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick(1000);
  fixture.detectChanges();

  expect(comp.packs.length).toBe(2);
}));
```

Check out this [live demo on stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-ddbkfc?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts)

p.s. the thing is, that when you mock your service method with rxjs `of` operator, it will act like a sync code, for example:

```
console.log(1);
of(2).subscribe(v => console.log(v));
console.log(3);
```

This code will console.log: 1, 2, 3.

But when you use Promise, it will act like an async code, for example:

```
console.log(1);
Promise.resolve(2).then(v => console.log(v));
console.log(3);
```

This code will console.log: 1, 3, 2.

This is why in case of using Promises for mocking your service method you have to write unit tests keeping in mind, that you are dealing with async code.

Comment: Thanks for the point, but the test still fails altough I added `tick(5000)` and `fakeAsync` before  checking the number of packs. I added the test code in the top of the question. The UI still show 0 packs. It looks like the test can't get through the async code.